# How to read existing text files without defining path

Tags: c#, .net, text, file-io

Most of the examples shows how to read text file from exact location (f.e. "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\test1.txt"). But, how to read text files without writing full path, so my code would work when copied to other computers. With visual studio I added 2 text files to project (console project) and don't know best way to read those files. Hope I described my problem clearly. Maybe I needed to add those txt files differentely (like directly to same folder as .exe file)?

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Something like `Read("test1.txt");' ??

Comment: Just like to add the following, besides the other answers, remember to add the file as a content so that it will be copied to the output directory. To do that, right click on the file that is in your project under the solution explorer (test1.txt), select properties and then select "Build Action" as Content and Copy to "Output Directory" "Copy always" or "Copy if newer".

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could use [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) with [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine):

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "fileName.txt");
```

Which will look for the file `fileName.txt` in the current directory of the application.

Comment: [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) returns _"A string that contains the path of the current working directory, and does not end with a backslash (\\)"_. Use `Path.Combine()` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: For a console application, the working directory is very often not the same as the directory that contains the executable. Why would these two text files which are associated with the program be located there?

Comment: it goes for the current drive's directory not the application's directory

Comment: @CME64 - It gets the current working directory of the application and works as expected.  Thanks for downvoting me.

Comment: @DarrenDavies don't take it personally. here is what worked for me `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and it's because my app isn't console .. you can edit your answer so that I can remove the down vote, I just noticed that the OP was asking about a console app.

Comment: @CME64 is right. The above solution does not work. It goes for the current drives directory. Get out of your feelings. If you fancy more up votes, i suggest you update your response. I will be down voting you once again.

Comment: @RansomAni-Gizzle - the solution does work and fulfils the OP's requirements, hence why it is the accepted answer. I would recommend that you learn and show respect to other community members, and also read the question that was actually asked before you downvote me once again.

Comment: @DarrenDavies you make a fair point about answering the question. I do apologise if what i said offended you. Just like CME64 the answer did not quite work for me but doesn't mean you did not answer the question. Happy to undo my down vote if you can modify your answer.

Comment: In my case, the leading back slashes of file name part need be removed. It should be like this: 
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "fileName.txt");
Otherwise, the result will be "\\fileName.txt" that is not expected. This is tested on VS 2015.

Comment: If you use Path.Combine() it automatically adds the path separator. Additional separators remove the current directory from path. It has to be: var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "fileName.txt");

Answer (score 42):

If your application is a web service, `Directory.CurrentDirectory` doesn't work.

Use `System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "yourFileName.txt"))` instead.

Comment: Yes. `Directory.CurrentDirectory` will be `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express`

Comment: I couldn't make it work, it returns always the path2 ( right hand side only ). I don't know if i'm missing something here.

Answer (score 16):

When you provide a path, it can be absolute/rooted, or relative.  If you provide a relative path, it will be resolved by taking the working directory of the running process.

**Example:**

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("Some\\Path.txt"); // relative path
```

The above code has the same effect as the following:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(
    Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Some\\Path.txt"));
```

If you have files that are always going to be in the same location relative to your application, just include a relative path to them, and they should resolve correctly on different computers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to decide which directory you want the file to be relative to. Once you have done that, you construct the full path like this:

```
string fullPathToFile = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
```

If you don't supply the base directory `dir` then you will be at the total mercy of whatever happens to the working directory of your process. That is something that can be out of your control. For example, shortcuts to your application may specify it. Using file dialogs can change it.

For a console application it is reasonable to use relative files directly because console applications are designed so that the working directory is a critical input and is a well-defined part of the execution environment. However, for a GUI app that is not the case which is why I recommend you explicitly convert your relative file name to a full absolute path using some well-defined base directory.

Now, since you have a console application, it is reasonable for you to use a relative path, provided that the expectation is that the files in question will be located in the working directory. But it would be very common for that not to be the case. Normally the working directory is used to specify where the user's input and output files are to be stored. It does not typically point to the location where the program's files are.

One final option is that you don't attempt to deploy these program files as external text files. Perhaps a better option is to link them to the executable as resources. That way they are bound up with the executable and you can completely side-step this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely need to know where the files to be read can be located. However, this information can be *relative* of course so it may be well adapted to other systems.

So it could relate to the current directory (get it from `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`) or to the application executable path (eg. `Application.ExecutablePath` comes to mind if using Windows Forms or via `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`) or to some special Windows directory like "Documents and Settings" (you should use `Environment.GetFolderPath()` with one element of the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration).

Note that the "current directory" and the path of the executable are not necessarily identical. You need to know where to look!

In either case, if you need to manipulate a path use the Path class to split or combine parts of the path.

Answer (score 1):

As your project is a console project you can pass the path to the text files that you want to read via the string[] args

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```

Within Main you can check if arguments are passed

```
if (args.Length == 0){ System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a parameter");}
```

Extract an argument

```
string fileToRead = args[0];
```

Nearly all languages support the concept of argument passing and follow similar patterns to C#.

For more C# specific see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cb20e19t.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This will load a file in working directory:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Yourfile.txt");

            Console.WriteLine("Your file content is:");
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

If your using console you can also do this.It will prompt the user to write the path of the file(including filename with extension).

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("****please enter path to your file****");
            Console.Write("Path: ");
            string pth = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your file content is:");
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(pth))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

If you use winforms for example try this simple example:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pth = "";
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pth = ofd.FileName;
                textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(pth);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get a path. See CurrentDirrectory mentioned. Also, you can get the full file name of your application by using 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
and then use Path class to get a directory name.

Comment: What happens if the assembly is located in the GAC?

Comment: A pb. So suitable not for any situation, but ok to be called from exe.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the leading `\\`

```
string path2 = "\\folderName\\fileName.json";
string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path2));
```

If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start with a separator character `\\` or a drive specification), the result is a concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator character. If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.

[Path.Combine Method (System.IO) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0)