# How to get Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ folder path in C#?

Tags: c#, special-folders

What is the best way to get this folder path programmatically : 
`Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local` ?

Comment: %systemroot% will get you to the windows folder...but as far as my research (done just now), there is no direct shortcut like we have with %appdata% for example

Comment: I believe this is the AppData path for the SYSTEM account.  So if you're running as the SYSTEM account, you should be able to use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) - though I haven't tested this.  If you're not running as the SYSTEM account, you probably have no business there.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath();
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't write comments sorry. What are you using the path for? Where is the application stored? This will get you there??

```
string path = "C:\\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local";
```

Provided C: is the name of the drive.

You really need to expand on your question a little bit.

Is this a duplicate question??

[How to read existing text files without defining path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405180/how-to-read-existing-text-files-without-defining-path)

Comment: I think you misunderstand what is _programmatically_ means.

Comment: Yes, I can, but I thought it might be a solution in terms of clean code to get this speciacial folder path

Comment: @SonerGönül No I don't. This is programmatic. I think what the OP is looking for is probably closer to what Rohan is stating above. It depends on how the OP is accessing it. If his app is there it's `System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, etc.);`  If he's accessing it directly from the program installed elsewhere he'll have to add more of the path. How is the OP accessing it. That's the question. Like I said. I can't comment so I guess @downvoters rule for the moment. Just trying to help.

Comment: @AndreiKarcheuski Can you add any more detail to your question? Please see my response above to Soner

Comment: @FrankPytel I just working on logging in c# application, I've got a task where I need to store log files in that folder. So I just looking how to get that folder path programmatically, the application can be installed on different OS.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`

In my project like this
`string configPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "MyProject", "SERVICER", "config.ini");`

It get Application Data Directory for all user ( contain System, Service, Guest,... ). I use it for save config of Service!!

Comment: Wrong. On my system, `CommonApplicationData` returns `C:\ProgramData`.

Comment: Sorry for it's wrong for your problem !!
But I don't know what you want !!

Why do you need to get the link like that ??
To store data shared between accounts, or systemprofile will be replaced in the context of the user ??

If for both of the above, the Environment.GetFolderPath method will give you quite similar results.

But if you really want to save to the `Windows\system32` directory, consider the option below:

`Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "config", Environment.UserName, "AppData", "Local");`

Comment: I need programmatically to create the directory `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop` (in case of 32-bit arhitecture) and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop` (in case of 64-bit arhitecture) if it does not exist, in order to use *MS Office Interop* from a *Windows* service.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your intentions from the beginning, this is how I think you can use: `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86), "config", "systemprofile", "AppData", "Local");`

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86)` will automatically give you the result of `system32` or `syswow64` depending on the executable computer.

Comment: Thanks for the information, *Trịnh*. You could post an answer with `SpecialFolder.SystemX86`! Is this enum member misnamed?

Comment: `// Summary:
            //     The Windows System folder. Added in the .NET Framework 4.
            SystemX86 = 41,` This is a summary of this member. I think maybe you are not using dotnet 4 or higher !! If so, unfortunately, I think this is the easiest way to get the results you want above.

Comment: Sadly, simple ways are only in dotnet 4 or higher. If you still want to achieve the goal, you can refer to the following, as far as I know it will work on most windows systems but I have not had the opportunity to test them on a lower-end computer!
[https://gist.github.com/DK189/11399b58985a1023f01d50118c23014a](Source code)

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, Trinh. Notice that the *Markdown* link formatting is broken. Here is the [right link](gist.github.com/DK189/11399b58985a1023f01d50118c23014a). By the way, you can test for 64 vs 32 bit architecture by checking `IntPtr.Size`.

Comment: Sorry for the markdown syntax! Regarding `IntPtr.Size` this has a disadvantage: if the application is built with the x86 flag, it will always have a value of 4, so in your request, using `IsWow64Process` in `kernel32` will always more accurate!

Comment: If the application is build for x86, it executes in the x86 environment and I need `Windows\system32\` in that case.

Comment: Well,... if you run x86 app on x64 environment, it always return `Windows\system32`,.. and on x64 environment, `systemprofile` only exists in `SysWOW64` folder!!

Answer (score -2):

You can get the path this way:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

Comment: Wrong. When called from a Windows service, `LocalApplicationData` returns `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local` on my system.