# Setting image source to application folder

Tags: c#, wpf, path

I'm trying to get an image from a certain path, but the path must only be referenced from the application's current folder and not from the *Local C:* drive.

My reason for this is because the application is going to get published soon and I can't reference the image to the same local location on my current PC, because the application is going to be used on a lot of other PC's and the path would not work on other someone else's computer.

This is the current path that works:

```
SetDefaultImage(new Binary(File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\mclaasse\\Desktop\\Haze Update\\Haze\\Haze\\Icons\\user6.jpg")));
```

And this is how I need it to be:

```
SetDefaultImage(new Binary(File.ReadAllBytes("Haze\\Icons\\user6.jpg")));
```

But i'm getting the error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Haze\Icons\user6.jpg'.

Is there a simple work around for getting my path to work?

Comment: Your answer probaby lies here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17405207/2245256

Comment: Why not load the image from an assembly resource?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read existing text files without defining path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405180/how-to-read-existing-text-files-without-defining-path)

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the comment man! How would I load it from a assembly resource?

Comment: @CareTaker22 From MSDN :)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf17tthe(v=vs.90).aspx. There are other solutions however if you want to load it directly from the markup in which case, you should read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419611/how-to-refer-to-embedded-resources-from-xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the references worked for me(I don't know why), but this worked:

```
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, "Icons\\user6.jpg");
```

Then check if the file that you are looking for exists:

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The default image does not exist", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but provided that you have an image file `user6.jpg` in your Visual Studio project in a project folder named `Images`, and the `Build Action` of the image file is set to `Resource`, you could simply load it from a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly):

```
var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/user6.jpg"));
```