# C# Accessing image inside project folder

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have a image uploader that stores my images on that project location:

C:\Users\example\source\Workspaces\project\projectsample\Content\Files

When I try to access this images with the following URL and code it breaks:

```
var fileURL = "~/Content/Files/image.png";
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileURL);
```

> Cannot find a part of the path

What I'm missing?

**EDIT**

Solved with the following: [How to read existing text files without defining path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405180/how-to-read-existing-text-files-without-defining-path) using AXMIM solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are on windows and not unix, so your fileURL is wrong. See [naming files, paths, and namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) for more info.

It should look like this:

```
var fileURL = @".\Content\Files\image.png";
```

EDIT: before its unclear, the `~` is the wrong character here, `/` or `\` does not matter in that regard.